# Security permissions for remote shared folders

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, file-sharing

I have two servers running Windows Server 2003, and I want copy files from one server (A), programmatically with a windows service running under the Local System account, to a shared folder on the other (B). I keep getting "access denied" errors, and I can't figure out what security settings I need to set to open the shared folder for writing.

This is what I've done on the recieving end:

1. On A, right-click on the folder to share, choose the tab "Sharing" and select "Share this folder". Set a share name.
2. Click "Permissions", add the group "Everyone" and give it full control.

I tried choosing the "Security" tab to give some permissions there as well, but the "Add" dialog only finds local users, despite the fact that B shows up in the "Workgroup computers" dialog. After further inspection, this is the case also for the "Permissions" dialog under the "Sharing" tab (are they the same?).

**Update:** I have done some further research, and found that the program on server A is run under the SYSTEM account. This is not something I dare change, because of the risk to break other things that this program also does (it's a build agent on our TeamCity CI server).

Thus, I need a way to give A\SYSTEM access to write in a shared folder on B, in a workgroup environment.

**Update 2:** I've now been able to do the following changes to my configuration:

- There is a user account on each server named TeamCity. They have the same passwords, and are both parts of their respective Administrators group (which I've verified by logging on via remote desktop to both servers using the same information).
- TeamCity (specifically \\B\TeamCity) has full control access to the shared folder on B.
- The build agent on A runs under the \\A\TeamCity account.

When I try to copy files this time, I get an error stating

> Could not find part of the path '\\B\Shared.Folder.Name'

I can copy the path from the error message and paste it into the address bar in Windows Explorer when logged on to the TeamCity account via Remote Desktop, and explorer navigates to the shared folder on B.

Comment: Since you use the word "workgroup", does that mean these servers are not members or controllers of a domain?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure (I'm not the one who administrates the network). If I look at the current security principals in some random folders on C in each server, it has the form of    `SERVERNAME\USERNAME` - I don't know if that's just the way it always is, or if it means both servers are in their own domains, where the domains are named after the servers.

Comment: So you don't have admin-level access?  If not, sharing files between the server will have to be set up by the network admin.

Comment: @charnley: I *do* have admin-level access - I'm just not the *individual* responsible for the network setup, so I don't know exactly how it works. I have admin access to be able to do this sort of thing every now and then, but the main network administration is carried out by someone else.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the security settings on the two folders ?

Comment: @Ninja, which settings windows would you like to see? I've been in a lot of them, and I'm not sure which ones actually convey any information that is useful to you...

Comment: Just an aside ... generally speaking you shouldn't give Full Control to the Everyone group. At the minimum use "Authorized Users" instead.

Comment: Go to your System Properties (Start  > right click My Computer > Properties) Go to the Computer Name tab. click "change." Between domain and workgroup, which radio button is selected?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, I know. I'll change it to something more restrictive as soon as I can figure out why it isn't working (because if it stops working when I increase the security requirements, I at least know where to look for the problem...)

Comment: @Daniel: It's in a workgroup.

Comment: One other thing, just to make sure this is going right. You need read permissions (at a minimum) on the computer files are being copied *from* and write permissions (at a minimum) on the computer being sent *to.* I'm talking about NTFS permissions, as discussed in the comment below. Share permissions should be full control.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827421 seems to address your error message ... Are you accessing the file via a mapped share, or are you accessing it directly via the UNC path, i.e. //ServerB/FolderName?

Comment: @Daniel: I'm accessing the path directly as `\\B\Folder.Name`. Also, the build runner is now also running under a separate user account, and not under LocalSystem anymore.

Comment: Note that it says Local system OR local use, something you won't be able to get away from without establishing a domain. You might try creating the service script it shows as a solution ... beyond that I'm afraid you've got me stumped.

Answer (score 4):

1. In a workgroup there is no central repository of users, so you have to manually duplicate the accounts on each workstation (or server in your case)
2. In a workgroup, **LocalSystem** accesses the network as Anonymous.

You should have the service run as a different account. Create an account with the same name/password on both machines, grant share permissions to the Service account and set the service to run as that rather than LocalSystem: start > run : services.msc
right click the service and go to properties. Change the logon to the user account you created.

If that doesn't work, you can configure the receiving folder to accept writes from Anonymous, but not read/execute. that would make the folder work like a drop box.

To answer your question about "security" and "share" permissions, no they are not the same. Security is NTFS permissions ... that's permission to access the file system. Share permissions is permission to access that resource across the network. The most restrictive of the two wins, so if you set Everyone to Full Control in security settings but Everyone to Read Only in share, you will get Full Control if you access the resource locally, but only read access if you try to use it from another computer.

Comment: Note that Share permissions are a legacy system (for Win9x systems).  They're still present, but generally speaking should always be set to Full Control and you should use NTFS permissions to restrict and control access.  Share permissions apply to the whole share, making them very ham-handed.  Additionally, they are more difficult to manage as you can easily have permission conflicts. Many people have a hard time believing they should do this, however.  Essentially, you need to think of Full Control on Share permissions as turning Share permissions off completely.

Comment: What Bacon Bits said.

Comment: To clarify, you do still need to share the folders to make them available (outside of the default admin shares). You just want to do all your permissions through NTFS.

Comment: +20 for Bacon Bits, if I could.

Comment: Why give the share full control??  While it's easier, it's violates the principle of least privilege. You can assign an administrative account full control, but never the Everyone user (which is what the original post suggested and you're replying to). NTFS isn't restricted enough to give Everyone full control.  For example, the Users group is granted access all over the place.  What if the share was to a folder that has Users with read permissions.  Then anyone that can authenticate to the domain can start reading (and maybe writing) to this server, even if they shouldn't have any access.

Comment: You're only sharing folders which you want to be shared. NTFS permissions restrict regardless of who actually has share rights. As far as the everyone group ... you're right. And you'll note that I made a comment on his OP saying as much. If you're sharing a folder, you should be verifying permissions anyway, if you're doing your job as an administrator, you shouldn't "accidentally" be giving permissions to anything.

Comment: From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754178.aspx: " Another approach is to set share permissions to Full Control for the Everyone group and to rely entirely on NTFS permissions to restrict access."

From a security perspective, the only benefit to having share permissions is that you might have some minimal protection against ignorance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - especially the clarification about share/security settings! I have investigated some more and updated the question with more details on the setup.

Comment: That could be problematic. I don't know of a way to do it without changing the user the service is running as or opening permissions to a not-good level. Are you certain you can't run it as another user? Might give it a try to see what happens ...

Otherwise, you're probably going to have to contact your software developer for support.

Comment: I can't believe some of the absurdities I'm seeing here. Share permissions are most certainly not a "legacy" system, they are the first level of security. They should be be used correctly, not just set at Full Control for everyone. NTFS permissions are the second layer, which provides greater control at the file and folder level but nobody should reach that level unless they have been specifically granted access via the share permissions. Ignorance of how to propely use share permissions is a massive security hole.

Comment: @John Gardeniers I hear what you're saying and that's what I was taught too, but from what Bacon and Evan have said ... I really can't think of any justifiable reason why you couldn't manage it that way. If you have incompetence allowing NTFS permissions to things people shouldn't be able to get to, then those same admins are just as likely to open up your "screen door" of share permissions as well. The security hole in your scenario is poor administration.

Comment: It should also be noted that it is easier to delegate access control to another user with share to full and using NTFS permissions. I give a group manager owner rights to their share and they are then able to add and remove users as fits their needs. Toss sharing in there and you have more problems.

Comment: @Scott Forsyth / @John Gardeniers: I believe Share Permissions are a legacy feature used for giving NTFS-like permission behavior to shared folders on filesystems like FAT (and, back in the day, HPFS). I'd argue that "repeating yourself" by specifying redundant Share Permissions adds unnecessary complexity and provides no real security. re: Scott and "What if ... Users with read permissions": Your NTFS permissions should be right, period. NTFS provides a single unambiguous method for controlling who can access filesystem resources and what access they have. Since Share Permissions ...

Comment: ... can't *add* any permission there's no "risk" in using "Everyone / Full Control" on Share Permissions to, effectively, remove the functionality of the "feature" from the OS. Worry about the NTFS permissions. There might be ways someone could access your files w/o going thru LanManServer (which enforces share permissions) but there's no way someone can get at the files w/o going thru NTFS.

Comment: @Even Anderson. I'm not suggesting that share permissions should "replace" NTFS permissions. I'm suggesting that *both* are essential. Once you grant Everyone or Authenticated Users full control to a Windows share, that server is fair game for anyone else in the domain. In fact, not only anyone else in the domain, even IIS local anonymous accounts, and other local accounts. Consider that the Window's default is to allow Users access to most folders. If that permission is left anywhere down the structure tree under the share, or reset by a Windows tool (installer, etc), you've opened the ...

Comment: server wide for them. Or, consider a windows share to a web server site path. If the IIS account u/p is obtained, there's a wide open share to it. It's shouldn't be done, but how many IIS site folders have Network Service left on disk? While your argument may be that you wouldn't leave that, you can see how easy it is for you or future administrators to make mistakes, not realizing that the front door is wide open. It's like saying that you leave the house front door unlocked because the bedroom doors are locked at night. Once you open wide the share, you're depending on you and all other ...

Comment: administrators and tools on never making a mistake on the NTFS permissions. It's my opinion that the windows share permissions need even more careful thought than NTFS since it's the doorway from the outside world. A mistake with NTFS permissions opens you to localized attacks. A mistake on the share opens you up to the world. If both are properly secured then it takes 2 mistakes to open up your network share to the world.

Comment: @Evan, share permissions have absolutely nothing to do with the file system. While the concept has been around since before the advent of a NTFS they are still completely distinct and separate. A simple example of how share permissions are used might help you understand. Department shares on a file server are restricted at the share level to department groups. If it is desirable to further limit permission for the members of the groups on files and/or folders the file system permissions should be used. Think of the share level permissions somewhat like a firewall before the file system.

Comment: @Scott Forsyth and @John Gardiners: I don't have the energy to argue about this. I've been using Windows NT since version 3.51. I *understand* it just fine. I've always used this "feature" this way and I'll continue recommending to other to use it in this way. NTFS permissions should be carefully planned and administered because the permission "buck" stops with them. "Share Permissions" are an ineffective "firewall" in my opinion, add complexity needlessly, and are an artifact of a bygone era. This medium doesn't lend itself to nuanced debate so we'll just have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @Evan Anderson.  I realize that your reputation proceeds you and I respect that.  I also agree that this medium doesn't lend itself to a detailed discussion.  It's fine to agree to disagree, and it's been worthwhile discussing this for as much as we did.

Comment: @Scott Forsyth: We'll have to sit down some time and hash this out at a face-to-face sometime... >smile<  (I suspect, though, we have a lot more opinions in common than not.)

Comment: @Scott Forsyth & @Evan Anderson, If you do have that conversation, I would very much like to hear what(if any) resolution you come to.

Comment: Guys - I strongly suggest that you move this conversation into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) if you want to continue it.

Answer (score 1):

The Local System account has no permission to access network resources. You will need to either have it run a process which can make the connection using suitable credentials or run the service under another account, which will still need to use suitable credentials to access the remote resource.

Comment: Isn't this what I said? Albeit in a roundabout way ...

Comment: @Daniel, you described a symptom. I described the reason for that symptom.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Please see my update with more information on accounts and setup.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely on a domain.  I would recommend using domain accounts if you are.  Pass-through authentication is possible, as mentioned already, but it's meant for a workgroup only, or if you're really restricted in what your domain admin will give you (although that suggests that you're doing something that your network admin won't support).

Here's how you can check if you're on a domain.

- Click *Start*.  Right-click *My Computer* and click *Properties*
- Click the *Computer Name* tab
- You can kind of tell from this screen, but click *Change*
- See if *Member of* is Domain or Workgroup.

If it's Workgroup, then use the pass-through authentication mentioned already. (exact same username/password on both machines)

However, if it's in a domain, what I recommend is that you ask your domain admin for a service account that you can use here.  Don't use your own account since password changes and such will cause your service to break.

In the Add dialog box, there is a *Locations...* button.  Click on that and make sure that your domain is selected (if you're going down the domain path).  That will give you access to domain users.

In either case (Workgroup or Domain), update your service account on A that you're using so that it uses that account, rather than using Local System.

Grant the new account only what permissions it needs to the Share and to the Security tab (NTFS permissions).  I wouldn't grant Everyone access to either the Share or NTFS, since that opens up your computer to anyone on the domain.

Note: sometimes it's fine to test using the Everyone group to remove permissions as an issue during testing, but be sure to tighten the final configuration.  That should be temporary only.

**Update:** Based on discussion in the comments, here's an example of a TeamCity config that's based on a working config of mine.

```
<property name="source.root" value="D:\svn\trunk\admin"/>
<property name="staging.directory" value="\\B\Shared.Folder.Name"/>
<property name="directory.to.upload" value="${source.root}\ControlPanel"/>

<target name="network.deploy">
<echo message="-------- NETWORK.DEPLOY ---------------"/>
    <copy todir="${staging.directory}" verbose="true">
        <fileset basedir="${directory.to.upload}">
            <include name="**/*"/>
            <exclude name="**/*.vb"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am in a workgroup environment, and regarding the user account I'm required to use the SYSTEM account on A. Please see my update.

Comment: Since it's TeamCity, can you use a task that allows you to specify the credentials?  The task that you're working with may support that.  Another option is to use FTP which also allows you to specify the credentials .  If those don't work, I would recommend changing the task that TeamCity runs under from System.  As long as the account is an administrator on the A server it should continue to work.  Then you are controlling the account to use on the network.  Otherwise Pass-through authentication won't work since Server A will see A$ (anonymous computer account) rather than a particular user.

Comment: @Scott: Thanks! I've updated my config so that the build agent runs under a specific account (which works thanks to your note on adding it to the admins group), but I still can't get the copy task to work. Please take a look at my updated question.

Comment: Looks like good progress, and good troubleshooting steps.  My assumption at this point is that the string format isn't what TeamCity expects.  Maybe it requires a trailing slash, or something of that nature.  I'll edit my reply with a TeamCity example that works for me.

Comment: I inserted this in my build script, and got an error saying "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\905a6382449fdab\NCVIB.SMSServices.targets(96, 7): error MSB4067: The element <fileset> beneath element <copy> is unrecognized.". Was this supposed to be a MSBuild snippet? If not, where (since not in my .build file) should I put it?

Comment: Hi Thomas.  TeamCity has its own build configuration.  Here's a good link on that: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Defining+and+Using+Build+Parameters+in+Build+Configuration.  For msbuild, the following two links looks like they provide a good example of the copy and impersonate syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160311/how-can-i-copy-files-as-a-different-user-from-msbuild

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by creating the same local user on each system.  Exact same username, exact same password.  Then run your service using those credentials.  Also set the NTFS ACLs as you were and give the local account on each system access, as well as in the share permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I am required to make this work with the SYSTEM account on one of the servers. See my update for details.