# Windows Share Permissions

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share

The share permissions on our file server shared folders are quite heterogeneous.  In particular, some seem to have been set up to mimic the NTFS permissions of the share.

I know that the default share permission are read only for EVERYONE.

I have also read an  [article](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Share-Permissions.html) that suggests that the best practice is to configure share permissions with Authenticated Users having Full Control.

Assuming I make sure that the NTFS permissions are sufficiently secure for these shares, is that what you would recommend for new/existing shares?

Comment: Yes. Yes it is.

Comment: Thats how I manage all of my windows shares.

Comment: Oh, no... not this discussion again. Please!

Comment: @Evan - sorry if I'm being repetitive - I did search this site first

Comment: @zen: No need to apologize. There was a fairly long discussion about this just a few days ago at: http://serverfault.com/questions/282098/security-permissions-for-remote-shared-folders/283139

Comment: @Evan - that was an interesting read.  I can see why I missed it as it was a side bar on the OP so thanks for the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Share permissions function as a filter on the NTFS permissions They take away what the NTFS perms give. The reasons why you want to do that are pretty rare, so setting the share perms as max permissive and doing everything else as a file system right is just fine and simpler.